# .Net integrating outlook in Web application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

How can I integrating an outlook calendar in my web application for managing employees so that I can assign tasks to only those employees not on leave?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're doing this from the server side, you will need to connect to the Exchange Server rather than integrate directly with an Outlook Calendar.

I have not done this myself but using Exchange Web Services it shouldn't cause too much trouble; check out the [Exchange Web Services Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb204119.aspx).